# How to select all properties with mention some properties which contains child object in select using linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentPropertyA { get; set; }
    public string ParentPropertyA { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children{get; set;}

}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string ChildPropertyA { get; set; }
    public string ChildPropertyB { get; set; }
    public List<ABC> AbcList { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select all Parent and Chield properties using linq query but I don't want to mention all in select like below,

```
conext.Parent.Select(x=>new Parent
{
    ParentId=x.ParentId,
    ParentPropertyA =x.ParentPropertyA ,
    Children=x.Children.Where(x=>x.IsDeleted!=true)
});
```

Instead I want to mention only properties that I need to include as child objects and others will get as it is but not getting success, I tried something like below,

```
conext.Parent.Select(x=>
{        
    x.Children=x.Children.Select(y=>{ y.AbcList; return y; }).Where(x=>x.IsDeleted!=true);
    return x;
});
```

Can anyone help me to achieve something like this?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to use the include keyword to load all the Children as well.

Sample code:

```
var model = await conext.Parent
    .Include(x => x.Children)
    .Where(x=>x.IsDeleted != true)
    .ToListAsync();
```

And then you can integrate an automapper and turn this base-specific object into another one

Automapper doc: https://automapper.org/

---

> There is no way without Include because EFCore takes up to 1 object
> down the hierarchy. Then he doesn't release them until you tell him
> to, and that's for performance purposes

---

Comment: I know this method but I don't want to use Include(), instead, I want to achieve this using Select(), Is there any way?